# How to Sort a PHP Simple XML Tree by Date

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm navgating through an XML Tree like this:

```
$notesXML = simplexml_load_string(XMLSTRING);

foreach($notesXML as $thenote){
  $noteAttr = $thenote->attributes();
  echo $noteAttr['modified'];
}
```

As you can see there is an attribute called "modified" as a part of the XML tree, what I want to do for now is just print out the XML tree in ascending or descending order based on the modified date.  BTW the date string is formatted like this: "Tuesday 6th of September 2011 03:49:14 PM"

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You could build an array of the elements that you want to sort, then use one of the [array sorting functions](http://php.net/array.sorting) to re-order them.

---

The snippet below uses [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/array_multisort) to sort them by descending date order. [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) is used to get the Unix timestamp from the date strings.

```
$notes = array();
$dates = array();
foreach ($notesXML as $note) {
    $notes[] = $note;
    $dates[] = DateTime::createFromFormat('l jS \of F Y H:i:s A', $note['modified'])->getTimestamp();
}
array_multisort($dates, SORT_DESC, $notes);

// Loop over $notes however you like
```